# compile ffmpeg report "libprotokit.a: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, compilation, ubuntu-21.04

On kubuntu 21.04 I successfully compiled ffmpeg from latest snapshot.

Now I try to add "--enable-libzmq" to configure command:

```
PATH="$HOME/.ffmpeg/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/.ffmpeg/build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/.ffmpeg/build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/.ffmpeg/build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/.ffmpeg/build/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --ld="g++" \
  --bindir="$HOME/.ffmpeg/bin" \
  --extra-version="...." \
  --arch=x86_64 \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-version3 \
...
  --enable-libxml2 \
  --enable-lv2 \
  --enable-libxcb \
  --enable-libxcb-shm \
  --enable-libzmq \
  --enable-nonfree  && \
PATH="$HOME/.ffmpeg/bin:$PATH" make -j4 && \
make install
```

and configure end with this error in config.log:

```
require_pkg_config libzmq libzmq >= 4.2.1 zmq.h zmq_ctx_new
check_pkg_config libzmq libzmq >= 4.2.1 zmq.h zmq_ctx_new
test_pkg_config libzmq libzmq >= 4.2.1 zmq.h zmq_ctx_new
pkg-config --exists --print-errors libzmq >= 4.2.1
check_func_headers zmq.h zmq_ctx_new -isystem /usr/include/mit-krb5 -I/usr/include/pgm-5.3 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -lzmq -lstdc++ -lpthread -lrt -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -lkrb5support -lsodium -pthread -lpgm -lpthread -lm -lnorm libprotokit.a -lxml2 -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lz -llzma -lm -lbsd -ldl -lmd
test_ld cc -isystem /usr/include/mit-krb5 -I/usr/include/pgm-5.3 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -lzmq -lstdc++ -lpthread -lrt -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -lkrb5support -lsodium -pthread -lpgm -lpthread -lm -lnorm libprotokit.a -lxml2 -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lz -llzma -lm -lbsd -ldl -lmd
test_cc -isystem /usr/include/mit-krb5 -I/usr/include/pgm-5.3 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -pthread libprotokit.a
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.AIehU3Rh/test.c
    1   #include <zmq.h>
    2   #include <stdint.h>
    3   long check_zmq_ctx_new(void) { return (long) zmq_ctx_new; }
    4   int main(void) { int ret = 0;
    5    ret |= ((intptr_t)check_zmq_ctx_new) & 0xFFFF;
    6   return ret; }
END /tmp/ffconf.AIehU3Rh/test.c
gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -DPIC -I/home/raz/.ffmpeg/build/include -std=c11 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -pthread -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1 -I/usr/include/lilv-0 -I/usr/include/sratom-0 -I/usr/include/sord-0 -I/usr/include/serd-0 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/home/raz/.ffmpeg/build/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/openjpeg-2.3 -I/home/raz/.ffmpeg/build/include/opus -I/home/raz/.ffmpeg/build/include/opus -D_REENTRANT -pthread -I/home/raz/.ffmpeg/build/include/libvmaf -I/home/raz/.ffmpeg/build/include -I/home/raz/.ffmpeg/build/include -I/home/raz/.ffmpeg/build/include -I/home/raz/.ffmpeg/build/include -I/home/raz/.ffmpeg/build/include -I/home/raz/.ffmpeg/build/include -isystem /usr/include/mit-krb5 -I/usr/include/pgm-5.3 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -pthread libprotokit.a -c -o /tmp/ffconf.AIehU3Rh/test.o /tmp/ffconf.AIehU3Rh/test.c
gcc: error: libprotokit.a: No such file or directory
ERROR: libzmq >= 4.2.1 not found using pkg-config
```

libzmq3-dev is installed and
I have this libprotokit.a in
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotokit.a

Why configure does not find this library?

libzmq.pc exist on the machine

```
dpkg -L libzmq3-dev|grep pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libzmq.pc

cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libzmq.pc 

prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: libzmq
Description: 0MQ c++ library
Version: 4.3.4
Libs: -L${libdir} -lzmq
Libs.private: -lstdc++  -lpthread -lrt
Requires.private:  krb5-gssapi libsodium openpgm-5.3 >= 5.3 norm libbsd
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

Comment: libzmq-dev version 4.3.4 has no pkg_config file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libzmq.pc` . ..... Get the file from "4.3.2" https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/libzmq3-dev .... and edit libzmq.pc line 8 to 4.3.4 . .... ( It's a twelve line text file.)

Comment: @KnudLarsen This file is already on the machine: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libzmq.pc`

Answer (score 1):

i have the same issue, fixed when remove line `--pkg-config-flags="--static"`

Comment: but I want to have a static compiled binary. I ended up compiling also libzmq from sources